# Laravel get count of unique/distinct users who commented on a post

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have some post records and each one has many comments that recorded in another table called `comments` and each comment belongs to a user

How can I get a list of posts with number of users they commented on each post?

-- A post can have multiple comments via one user, so the number of comments is not right, I'm looking for number of users.

I tried:

```php
$posts = Post::query()
               ->where('category',$request->input('category'))
               // other conditions
               ->get();

$numberOfUsers=[];
forech($posts as $post){
    $numberOfUsers[$post->id] = $post->comments()->groupBy('user')->count();
}
```

But I don't know if it's the best way or not.

---

I have tried `belongsToMany`, `hasMany` and `hasManyThrough` with and without `groupBy`, but still getting number of comments instead of number of users.

Comment: cant you solve this using [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_withCount) ([see docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models))?

Comment: @BagusTesa Not really. The goal is getting number of users they are commented, I don't know how to create the right relation for it, I already used `HasManyThrough` and `BelongsToMany`

Comment: i think that's how you do it with eloquent. If you want like "1 liner", just use join() and raw query since eloquent has limit

Answer (score 0):

Create userComments relation on Post model:

```
return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->group_by('comments.user_id');
```

then try this query:

```
Post::withCount('userComments')->where('category',$request->input('category'))->get();
```

Not sure this is the best way, maybe some people with more experience will comment below

Comment: It's not working and fetches the count of comments actually.

Answer (score 0):

a man once asked,

> cant you solve this using `withCount()`?

**It can't**.

Even so, we can still abuse Eloquent relationship for our cause. You should define a relationship between `Post` and `User` as a many-to-many relationship using `Comment` as pivot. We then add a helper - an accessor - for remapping the retrieved relations into number.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    ... a bunch of unrelated stuff
    
    //relationship Post to User through Comment
    public function commentUsers()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'comments', 'post_id', 'user_id');
    }

    //accessor
    public function getCommentUsersAttribute()
    {
      if(!array_key_exists('commentUsers', $this->relations))
      {
        $this->load('commentUsers');
      }
      
      return $this->getRelation('commentUsers')
                  ->unique('id')
                  ->count();
    }
}
```

And then run your Eloquent query by loading the `commentUsers` relationship:

```
App\Models\Post::with('commentUsers')
               ->where(...
               ... your where clauses
               ->get()
```

And then, you can use the accessor (in old format - Laravel 5) namely `getCommentUsersAttribute` on each of the `Post` instances this way:

```
$post->commentUsers;
```

Your Eloquent query should run two different query when you call `get()` - much better than doing it for every single posts. One for fetching the post with constraint. The other for retrieving the users. An excerpt from `DB::getQueryLog`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(21) "select * from `posts`"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(2.96)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(212) "select `users`.*, `comments`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `comments`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `comments` on `users`.`id` = `comments`.`user_id` where `comments`.`post_id` in (1, 2, 3)"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(0.8)
  }
}
```

Most of the heavy lifting is done on the database side, though the final counting is done on app side using accessor.

> *One can always tarnish themselves with `DB::raw()` as desperate means in the face of adversary.*

Though, to be fair, some might complain the resulting query is suboptimal and they can write better query - but its a power we forgo to gain enormous convenience called ORM.

Comment: I don't think you red the part that says:
`-- A post can have multiple comments via one user`


And the problem is right there, I already did what you said and it returns the number of records they are related to the post, I've double checked your answer and did it again but same result.

Comment: @Omid sorry, forgot to add dupes in test data.

Answer (score 0):

The **comments** table has column for

- **post_id** which associates it with a **Post**
- **user_id** which associates it with a **User**

So you can define a relation on the **Post** model to get all users who commented on the Post, by using **comments** table as pivot table to associate **Post** records with **User** records via **Many-to-Many** relationship

```php
public function commentUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'comments')->distinct('user_id');
}
```

And to get a count of all users who have commented on a given **Post**, you can use subquery

```php
$posts = Post::query()
    ->addSelect(['commentUsersCount' => Comment::selectRaw('count(distinct user_id)')
        ->whereColumn('post_id', 'posts.id')
    ])
    // If you want to eager load distinct users who commented on the post
    //->with('commentUsers')
    ->get();
```

**commentUsersCount** will be the count of (unique/distinct) users who have commented on the post

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Subquery Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#subquery-selects)